# SimpleMembershipProvider WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection The login from an untrusted domain

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, exception, simplemembership

I export the database to the server and I've problem. When I start application I see this error

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>   Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", 
                                         "Users", 
                                         "Id", 
                                         "Nick", 
                                         autoCreateTables: true);
```

ConnectionString:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" 
connectionString="Data Source=SQL5008.Smarterasp.net;Initial Catalog=DB_9CB321_Szklarnia; 
User Id=DB_9CB321_Szklarnia_admin;
Password=mypassword; Integrated Security=True"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Comment: Ok, I added <add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="true" /> and delated Integrated Security=True" and working.

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: 2012, but database is in web hosting. 2012, but database is in web hosting. Application is working now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you are providing in your connection string UserName and password, so you can change from Integrated Security=True to

```
Integrated Security=False
```

and if the user 'DB_9CB321_Szklarnia_admin' has rights to connect it will work.
When Integrated Security=True the userID and password will be ignored and attempt will be made to connect using current domain credentials.